# Windows Firewall claims uTorrent is infected

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall, utorrent

I installed uTorrent from the official site.  When I tried to start it, Windows Firewall displayed an error message that the program could be infected and dangerous for the PC (I have Windows 7).

The only way to use uTorrent is to deactivate Windows Firewall, but then I hava no protection for the PC.

The strange thing is that this uTorrent version come from the official site.
How do I determine whether there is an actual infection, and if not, get Windows Firewall to not give a false positive message?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just create an exception for the program?

Comment: It is not unheard of that official sites are hacked. I would upload the primary executable to [VirusTotal](https://virustotal.com/) to make sure.

Comment: Thanks , yes i would create an exception , the strange thing was only that the problem come from an official site.

Comment: I'm going to reinstall the program an try again , than if it is impossible to use create the exception

Comment: uTorrent DO contains malware, you can easily find lots of reference on google. Just use a opensource replacement?

Comment: The Windows Firewall does not display messages like that. Please provide a screenshot of the message.

Comment: Thanks Sam  , it was a malware , i will use a replecement. Thanks